# How to delete all files in a directory tree older than 10 days using a VBS script?

Tags: vbscript

I have a server with lots of folders inside `C:\data`. I talk about around 5000 subfolders, whereby each folder has a random name such as `sgshVSHsXx.wjwuhHHS`.

Each of those folders contains a subfolder with name `DB` and each of those `DB` folders contains some database files, also with random file names and random file extensions.

I need to go through all those `DB` folders and delete every file that is older than 10 days.

I presume I could use some VBS for that, but have not much experience with it. Could someone throw some light on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course batch or command prompt is suited to this

```
forfiles /p "c:\data" /m * /s /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

and is one line.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as a .vbs file

```
set args = wscript.arguments
if args.count <> 2 then
    wscript.echo "Syntax: " & wscript.scriptname & " <path> <days>" 
    wscript.quit
end if

path = args(0)
killdate = date() - args(1)

arFiles = Array() 
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 

SelectFiles path, killdate, arFiles, true 

nDeleted = 0 
for n = 0 to ubound(arFiles) 

  on error resume next 'in case of 'in use' files... 
  arFiles(n).delete true 
  if err.number = 0 then 
     nDeleted = nDeleted + 1 
  end if 
  on error goto 0 
next 

sub SelectFiles(sPath,vKillDate,arFilesToKill,bIncludeSubFolders) 
  on error resume next 
  set folder = fso.getfolder(sPath) 
  set files = folder.files 

  for each file in files 
    dtlastmodified = null 
    on error resume Next 
    dtlastmodified = file.datelastmodified 
    on error goto 0 
    if not isnull(dtlastmodified) Then 
      if dtlastmodified < vKillDate then 
        count = ubound(arFilesToKill) + 1 
        redim preserve arFilesToKill(count) 
        set arFilesToKill(count) = file 
      end if 
    end if 
  next 

  if bIncludeSubFolders then 
    for each fldr in folder.subfolders 
      SelectFiles fldr.path,vKillDate,arFilesToKill,true 
    next 
  end if 
end sub
```

to run:
.vbs ""

example:
c:\delete.vbs "c:\test folder\" 10

Make sure you run from an admin command prompt

#
source:http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/282-delete-old-files-with-recursion